# requestPermissions not showing permission dialog on device, works well on Android studio emulator

Tags: android

Facing weird issue with requestPermissions method of activity. It is now showing if I debug on device. Works well if I debug app on Android studio emulator.
Below is the code for requesting permission.

```
public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here is AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Device I'm running for debugging is OnePlus 1. Am I missing anything?

Here are some additional logs while trying to requestPermissions:

```
07-08 19:42:14.222 798-815/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS pkg=com.android.packageinstaller cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10206 on display 0
07-08 19:42:14.224 798-815/? W/ActivityManager: Bad activity token: android.os.BinderProxy@ae80cbb
                                                java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$Token
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.forTokenLocked(ActivityRecord.java:424)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.isInStackLocked(ActivityStack.java:467)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.isInAnyStackLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:592)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1484)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1090)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4077)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:4064)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:162)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2670)
                                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
07-08 19:42:14.224 798-815/? W/ActivityManager: Bad activity token: android.os.BinderProxy@ae80cbb
                                                java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$Token
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.forTokenLocked(ActivityRecord.java:424)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.isInStackLocked(ActivityStack.java:467)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.isInAnyStackLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:592)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1484)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1090)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:4077)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:4064)
                                                    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:162)
                                                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2670)
                                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
07-08 19:42:14.225 798-815/? W/ActivityManager: startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS flg=0x800000 pkg=com.android.packageinstaller cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity (has extras) }
07-08 19:42:14.258 12029-12029/? I/GrantPermissionsActivity: No package: null
                                                             android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
                                                                 at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:138)
                                                                 at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.getCallingPackageInfo(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:349)
                                                                 at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.onCreate(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:99)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: is OnePlus 1 having MarshMallow in it?

Comment: yes, it has MarshMallow

Comment: Is the permissions is already accepted in the device app settings?

Comment: as I have minSdkVersion 23, runtime permission should work. or do I still require to check device app settings for permission?

Comment: kindly share which activity you are using the above code ??

Comment: I'm using AppCompatActivity

Comment: found an issue that causing this behaviour. I was requesting permissions from child activity. When I tried with ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getParent(),new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1); it worked somehow. Not clear about reason though. Thanks so far guys.

Comment: @priyankbrahmbhatt: pls answer your comment and accept it. It really helpful..

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

TO

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/3142192

Comment: that was my initial try. but that was also not working

Comment: @priyankbrahmbhatt Try to add context **ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )**

Comment: same result with ContextCompat